# How to integrate my testbench in chisel with a C++ library?

Tags: scala, chisel

I have a testbench in chisel that uses the peekpoketester. I have a C++ library that I want to use in the testbench. Is there a way to do this in chisel/scala?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a series of flags that can be added in the `Driver.execute` that let you control the command line used to compile the c++ simulator generation.

```
  -ttc, --test-command <value>
                           Change the command run as the backend. Quote this if it contains spaces
  -tmvf, --more-vcs-flags <value>
                           Add specified commands to the VCS/Verilator command line
  -tmvf, --more-vcs-c-flags <value>
                           Add specified commands to the CFLAGS on the VCS/Verilator command line
  -tvce, --vcs-command-edits <value>
                           a file containing regex substitutions, one per line s/pattern/replacement/
  -tmif, --more-ivl-flags <value>
                           Add specified commands to the ivl command line
  -tmicf, --more-ivl-c-flags <value>
                           Add specified commands to the CFLAGS on the ivl command line
  -tice, --ivl-command-edits <value>
                           a file containing regex substitutions, one per line s/pattern/replacement/
  -tmvlf, --more-vlog-flags <value>
                           Add specified commands to the vlog command line
  -tmvsf, --more-vsim-flags <value>
                           Add specified commands to the vsim command line startup
  -tmvsd, --more-vsim-do-cmds <value>
                           Execute specified commands within vsim interpreter before simulation run
  -tmvscf, --more-vsim-c-flags <value>
                           Add specified commands to the g++ vpi compilation command line for use with vsim backend
  -tvsce, --vsim-command-edits <value>
                           a file containing regex substitutions, one per line s/pattern/replacement/
```

To see this list just add a temporary "--help", to the arguments passed to Driver.execute and these (and many other options will show up in your output)

These options or something similar also appear in [ChiselTest](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-testers2) the newer unit test framework for chisel